# Is there a way to reset / clear a RegEx of all matches?

Tags: regex, vba, ms-office

```
Dim regExp As RegExp
Dim regMaC As MatchCollection
Dim regMat As Match
For Each A in B
  regExp.Pattern = "(\w*)"  ' Doesn't match in 2nd run, keeps (\W*) match
  Set regMaC = regExp.Execute(A.Body)
  If regMaC Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "No match in 1"
  Else
    For Each regMat in regMaC
      Debug.Print regMat.Submatches(0)
    Next regMat
  End If
  regExp.Pattern = "(\W*)"  ' Matches in 1st run
  Set regMaC = regExp.Execute(A.Body)
  If regMaC Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "No match in 2"
  Else
    For Each regMat in regMaC
      Debug.Print regMat.Submatches(0)
    Next regMat
  End If
  ' Would like to clear all matches here
Next A
```

In this example the matches are being preserved into the second run but is there an easy to just clear the match from the second pattern.
This isn't an issue if the first expression keeps matching and overwriting the previous match.

Comment: This code cannot work. Where do you actually execute the RegExp? I would think you would need to use `A` somewhere. Seems like you removed too much code for demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, i will add the execution step. `A` is in my case an `Outlook.MailItem` in `Outlook.MailItems` of an Inbox folder which it should go through.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include some code that shows how you *execute* the RegExp? This is essential...

Comment: Now its roughly how I set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following statement as the first inside the loop:

```
regExp = new RegExp
```

Remarks:

You may want to do this also half-way the loop (depending on your expectations), and maybe set the `Global` property to `True`.